I don't know what the pronoun "it" refers to in this sentence
I'm trying to learn React Context from its official documentation.

Context lets a parent—even a distant one!—provide some data to the entire tree inside of it.
https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context 
(emphasis mine)

What word does the pronoun "it" refer to? Does it refer to "parent", "context", or perhaps (though that's unlikely) to "tree"?

The antedecent of "it" is "context".

@TimR How do you know? Clearly, both a parent and a context can contain a tree.

Sometimes how we understand a sentence is probabilistic.  Here, the programming "context" is the subject under discussion, so to concern yourself about a tree inside a node merely because that is possible is to go down a rabbit-hole. It would be an irrelevant side-tracking of the main topic, which is the mechanism of shared context by which a parent node is able to make data visible to the entire tree it contains.

Furthermore, if the reference is unclear, one can always read on to see what the author meant.  You're not a runtime, but a human, and you can decide whether the error is severe enough that you must decide to stop dead in your tracks, or continue and see what happens.

It may be the tree itself, but this is major techie talk, not standard English.

the reference is to the parent component ... a component can contain a tree of other components

If I read the sentence in isolation (on its own), I certainly would say that 'it' refers to 'parent' rather than 'context'. This is because 'context' is the setting or environment. Telling someone to "Hey, close that" could mean a door or window or container. The context (maybe you're in a kitchen) would help the other person understand which thing should be closed.
However, I went to the page and read further. In React, context is a thing that a programmer can create to simplify their code. The programmer can create an object which includes certain 'props' (I assume this is supposed to be a charming shortened form of properties) from a parent object in a tree. The context object can them be used to assign certain props to various children or grandchildren or great-grandchildren in the tree rather than assign the props to each one separately.
So 'it' really does apply to 'context' rather than to 'parent'.
